# Filter results after date SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I need to filter my query to extract the results between 25th of the previous month and 25th of the current month. The SP receives a date as parameter, which I am using to extract the current month.I tried to make some casting but I can't figure how to deal with the January month when the last month has a different year(there must be a more efficient way also)

```
@Date smalldatetime --received as parameter
select *
from mytable
where mytable.mydate between '25/'+cast(MONTH(@date)-1 as varchar(2))+'/'+cast(YEAR(@date) as varchar(4)) and '25/'+cast(MONTH(@date) as varchar(2))+'/'+cast(YEAR(@date) as varchar(4))
```

Comment: SQL version? Answers may vary greatly. That is: SQL 2012 introduced `datefromparts()`, which you could use in combination with `year()`, `month()` and `day()` to get far clearer code than that pile of hacky string manipulation that probably falls apart in a different locale.

Comment: SQL Server version underscore means. SQL is a language specified by ISO/ANSO. Current ISO SQL version is SQL-2016. Do not confuse SQL and SQL Server...

Comment: Whoops, yup, that's an important clarification; thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just do:

```
select t.*
from t
where mydate >= dateadd(month, -1, datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 25)) and
      mydate < datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 25)
```

I would use `datefromparts()` rather than trying to construct a date string for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do any casting. SQL Server's datetime functions are quite versatile. Try this:

```
SELECT    *
FROM       mytable
WHERE    mytable.mydate BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, 25, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @Date) - 1, 0)) AND DATEADD(DAY, 25, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @Date), 0))
```